# pip --version returns SyntaxError (invalid syntax) after installation

Tags: python, python3, pip

OS: Debian 8

Python: v3.4.2 (uninstalled v2.7 and v3.5 in order to reduce possible root causes)

I installed pip for Python 3 as per documentation:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv python3-pip
```

Afterwards, checking the version results in a SyntaxError:

```
$ python3 -m pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please note the path to Python version 3.4, while the following check points to version 3.5:

```
$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, which pip points to another path:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

What is going wrong? How can I fix PIP?

I need it to install the tool elastalert.

What I have tried so far:

1. Uninstalled PIP for Python 3.5 and checked version again.
2. Uninstalled PIP for Python 2.7 and checked version again.
3. Uninstalled Python v3.5 (`apt remove --purge`) and checked version again.
4. Uninstalled Pyton v2.7 and checked version again.
5. Uninstalled Python v3.4 and checked version again.
6. Re-installed Pyhton v3.4 and checked version again.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.

Comment: @David OK, thanks!

Comment: Also, you cannot uninstall the default Python versions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [phd's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871131/3231743), the root cause is the PIP version installed by default being not compatible with the old Python version 3.4. The crucial clue was the `f""` being only supported by Python v3.6+.

So I've uninstalled PIP and re-installed PIP 19.1.1 as follows:

0. Uninstall incompatible PIP provided by distro repository:

   ```
   sudo apt remove --purge python3-pip
   ```
1. Download a `get-pip.py` version which is compatible with my Python version 3.4:

   ```
   curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.4/get-pip.py
   ```
2. Install PIP (in my case with `sudo` as global installation and with `-E` to apply proxy settings to `sudo` session):

   ```
   sudo -E python3 get-pip.py
   ```
3. Optional: Upgrade PIP to ensure it's the latest available version:

   ```
   sudo -E python3 -m pip install --upgrade "pip < 19.2"
   ```
4. Check version:

   ```
   python3 -m pip --version
   ```

   Ouput:

   ```
   pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip (python 3.4)
   ```

Comment: OMG finally. I have read dozens of answers and none solved this problem but your answer did. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent answer, really clear and it saved me today